# Has anyone found this formula before?

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

I found this formula.
\begin{equation}
\sum_{\lambda \vdash n}\frac{2^{l(\lambda)}}{z_{\lambda}}=n+1
\end{equation}
where $\lambda \vdash n$ means that $\lambda$ is an integer partition of $n$, $l(\lambda)$ is the length of $\lambda$ and if $\lambda=(1^{m_{1}},2^{m_{n}},\cdots,n^{m_{n}})$, $z_{\lambda}=m_{1}!m_{2}!\cdots m_{n}! 1^{m_{1}}2^{m_{2}}\cdots n^{m_{n}}$.\

Has anyone found it before?

Comment: Please clarify this question by spelling out the definitions involved and some background about how you came across this formula. (For instance, did you prove that it's true? Did you just verify it for a few values? Etc.) See also: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960

Answer (score 3):

From symmetric function theory we know that $$ h_n(x)=\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \dfrac{1}{z_\lambda}p_\lambda(x) $$ where $h_n(x)$ is the complete homogeneous symmetric function and $p_\lambda(x) : \lambda \vdash n$ are the power sum symmetric functions.

Now specialize $x$ to $x_1=1,x_2=1$ and $x_i = 0 $ for $i \geq 2$. Then the power sum symmetric function $p_k(x)=\sum_i x_i^k$ specializes to $2$ and hence $p_\lambda(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{l(\lambda)} p_{\lambda_i}(x)$ specializes to $2^{l(\lambda)}$.

On the other hand, $h_n(x)=\sum_{1 \leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq ... \leq i_n} x_{i_1}...x_{i_k}$ specialize to $n+1$. This is because each term of the form $x_1^jx_2^{n-j}$ for $j=0,...,n$ contributes $1$ and the rest of the terms contribute $0$.